# Filtering files with -notcontains

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I'm trying to filter a file extension equal to `.config` and file name doesn't contains vshost in the name, so I run this script:

```
$files = dir
foreach($file in $files) {
    if($file.Name -notcontains 'vshost' -and $file.Extension -eq '.config') {
        Write-Host $file;
    }
}
```

But the output still contains files with `vshost` in the name:

```
foo.exe.config
foo.vshost.exe.config
foo2.vshost.exe.config
```

the expected output is:

```
foo.exe.config
```

What am I missing and how do I fix this?

Comment: `-notcontains` is collection operator, not string operator. `-notlike '*vshost*'`

Comment: Sorry downvotes for the confusing, it's the first time I'm ever using power shell script.

Comment: It's probably because you should have figured this out by reading the help (shows little research effort)  :-)  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-notcontains` is used to look for an item in an array, ex. `$array -notcontains $singleitem`. You need to use `-notlike` or `-notmatch` (regex-patterns). Ex.

```
if($file.Name -notlike '*vshost*' -and $file.Extension -eq '.config') {
```

or

```
if($file.Name -notmatch 'vshost' -and $file.Extension -eq '.config') {
```

Answer (score 3):

`-contains/-notcontains` is used to check if a list contains an element. You can use the `-like / -notlike` or the `-match` operator.

In your sample you could use

```
$files = dir
foreach($file in $files) {
    if($file.Name -notlike '*vshost*' -and $file.Extension -eq '.config') {
        Write-Host $file;
    }
}
```

A reference can be found [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_conditional_operators.htm)